# Search string in database

Tags: vb.net, string, search

Lets say i have file.txt
file.txt contains:

```
banana peach orange
black white yellow
car train airplane
```

I want a code in vb.net which contains:

```
Button1 (Search button)
Textbox1 (What you want to search)
Listview1 (Shows results)
```

So basicly when i type peach in Textbox1 and press search on Button1 i want it to show banana peach orange in Listview1.
If anyone could help me with this it would be greatly appreciated as i don't have any experience with vb.net.

Kind regards,
Eric Sturdivant

Comment: `I want a code` is not a question.  SO is not a code server where you type in your wants and desires and code comes out.  Write some code, and when you get stuck post a (real) question.  See [Ask] and also take the [Tour]

Comment: Alright im sorry, I'm new to the forum and i have never coded anything i'm also only 15 years old. Anyways i will search around on SO to see if i can find anything usefull.

Comment: Try breaking it down into the steps ... such as loading each line of the file into a collection, searching the collection for a match and displaying the result(s). You can then find plenty of info out there on the more specific steps. For the searching part try using Linq or a foreach. The way you worded your question it seems like you're asking us to do your homework.

Comment: Don't just search around for other people's code. Think about the problem, solve it and then try to write code that implements your solution. People think they can't solve a problem because they have no programming experience but programming experience is actually irrelevant to that part. Let's say that you had to write out a list of steps that a person had to follow the get the desired result manually, i.e. with pen and paper and no computer involvement. Could you do that? Of course you could, so do it.  Write out those steps and THEN try to write code to implement those steps.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
For Each line In File.ReadAllLines("example.txt")
If line.Contains(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim leftPart As String = line.Split(" ")(0)
    Dim middle As String = line.Split(" ")(1)
    Dim right As String = line.Split(" ")(2)
    Dim newItem As New ListViewItem(leftPart)
    newItem.SubItems.Add(middle)
    newItem.SubItems.Add(right)
    ListView1.Items.Add(newItem)
End If
Next
End Sub
```

That should at least give you idea where to go from now.